# Why don't we consider drain-bulk voltage instead of source-bulk voltage in body effect?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, physics

Why don't we consider drain-bulk voltage instead of source-bulk voltage in body effect?

For example, in the threshold voltage formula, we have source-bulk voltage, not drain-bulk voltage.

Answer (score 5):

The reason for this is pinch-off.

[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a9/MOSFET_functioning.svg/1024px-MOSFET_functioning.svg.png]

[Image source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:MOSFET_functioning.svg)

In the saturation region of the MOSFET, the inversion layer does not span all the way from source to drain (bottom right picture). Instead, it pinches off at some mid-way point that depends on the drain-source voltage, and is not connected to the drain. This means that the entire inversion region is at the potential of the source terminal; the drain potential is effectively disconnected and does not have any major influence on the operation of the MOSFET.

The body effect is about the variation of the MOSFET's threshold voltage with increasing source-bulk voltage. When the threshold voltage is applied to the gate, the MOSFET is necessarily in the saturation region (since Vgs-Vth is zero, any positive Vds puts it into saturation). As explained above, this means that the entire inversion layer is at the source potential, and the drain voltage does not influence the MOSFET's behavior at the threshold. Therefore, the body effect's influence on the threshold voltage is independent of the drain voltage.

Comment: Please provide a link or citation for the graphics you copied into your answer. The policy for this site is that answers should give proper attribution for material from other sources.